# How can I install deb packages offline to install software and keep it updated in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: server, package-management, deb

I am in a company with local network configured to forbid any network connection from my floor, but I have an online springboard host which can connect with my three virtual machines. In other words I have an online machine and three offline machines to build a cluster. They are both Ubuntu server 16.04 with exactly the same version.

Ubuntu Server doesn't come with some software I need, such as ssh and vim. I was able to bundle all dependencies online, and use `nc -l` to push them to three offline machines.

But what can I do next to install those `.deb` files on my offline machines?

I can't use apt-offline, snaptic... Because I am offline and these systems are bare without any tools, no GUI tools. My USB port is also not available, and no CD/DVD drive is available.

So the only thing I can do is copy all the `.deb` files under `/var/cache/apt/archives` on my online machine to the offline virtual machines. Having done so, how can I install all the software so that I can maintain the always offline VMs up to date with online one? It makes sense to be sustainable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: I have paste my question,sorry for that@pomsky

Comment: I have review this question before I post this,my situation is a little knotty,I have update my post@karel

Comment: I suggest you delete on SO. Your question is more suitable here.

Comment: You will find an answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: The easiest is `dpkg -i` but the choice is yours.

Comment: No I indeed wanna build a local repository,dpkg is hard to maintain afterwards@JoKeR

Comment: Yes,Thank you for advice,sorry for that,I've new to here@Zanna

Comment: I indeed found a workaround,but it seems I've got another problem while I enforce it,alas,I post it with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103498/ubuntu-16-apt-the-repository-http-xxx-x-x-xxx-repo-release-does-not-have-a)@karel